# trying to use angular-timer, am getting this error "TypeError: moment.locale is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, momentjs, angular-timer

I have been trying to use the angular-timer, in my angularjs app, but I keep getting this error "TypeError: moment.locale is not a function".
  I added my scripts like so. please can someone help me out?

```
<script src="assets/_plugins/classroom/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/_plugins/classroom/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/_plugins/classroom/angular-timer/humanize-duration.js"></script>
<script src="assets/_plugins/classroom/moment/min/locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/_plugins/classroom/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mentioned you 'added my scripts like so'. There is no code being displayed at the moment in your question, you may want to review that.

Comment: Am sorry. Typo. You can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your order might be wrong. I would guess that angular-timer depends on moment, locals and moment-with-locals, so it should be last in the loading order.

**Update:**

Alternatively, as plugin implementation can be problematic. I created a working demo of a custom timer/countdown for a user's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720166/making-a-10-second-timer-for-an-angular-js-application/38721823#answer-38721823), perhaps it can be adapted for your solution or at least lead you in the right direction.

You set an end time and supply a function to run when that end time is met.

Comment: Ok, and you've definately added these as dependancies in your angular.module declaration? If not i'm afraid from this point it's just guess work unless you can replicate the issue in a codepen/jsbin. It's a little too vague without seeing your codebase.

Comment: the thing is, am trying to use the angular-timer to count down, so i downloaded and installed angular-timer, humanize-duration, and moment-with-locales. But i keep getting this error "TypeError: moment.locale is not a function".